# How to perform Sequelize join

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an Express app running in nodejs and uses Sequelize to work with a MySQL database.  In my db logic, I have a 1-to-Many relationship from `ChatRoom` to `UserChatRoom`.  When I try to preform a join using this code:

```
var userId = 1;

db.ChatRoom.findAll({ include: [{
                model: db.UserChatRoom,
                where: {
                    ucrIdChatUser:userId 
                },
                required: false
            }]})
```

I get the following error message on the console:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: UserChatRoom is not associated to ChatRoom!
    at validateIncludedElement
```

I would like to get the join query working and would appreciate help.  I've tried to enforce associations at the end of `index.js`.  This script loads the models in this folder when called the app starts and is taken from the Sequlize website.

Note: `UserChatRoom.ucrIdChatRoom` is a foreign key to `UserChat.idChatRoom`

Models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType){
    var ChatRoom = sequelize.define("ChatRoom",{
        idChatUser: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        crName: {
            type: DataType.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        crDateInserted: {
            type: DataType.DATE
        },
        crDateUpdated: {
            type: DataType.DATE
        },
        crIsOpen: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0
        }

    })

    return ChatRoom;

}
```

and

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType){
    var UserChatRoom = sequelize.define("UserChatRoom",{
        idUserChatUser: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        ucrIdChatUser: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER
        },
        ucrIdChatRoom: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER
        },
        ucrDateInserted: {
            type: DataType.DATE
        },
        ucrDateUpdated: {
            type: DataType.DATE
        }

    })

    return UserChatRoom;

}
```

`index.js`:

```
"use strict";

var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config    = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config.json'))[env];

if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL,config);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js")  && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.UserChatRoom.hasOne(db.ChatUser);
db.UserChatRoom.hasOne(db.ChatRoom, { foreignKey: 'ucrIdChatRoom' , foreignKeyConstraint:true });

db.ChatUser.belongsTo(db.UserChatRoom, { foreignKey: 'ucrIdChatRoom' , foreignKeyConstraint:true});

db.ChatRoomMessage.hasOne(db.UserChatRoom, { foreignKey: 'crmIdUserChatRoom' , foreignKeyConstraint:true });

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the relationship both ways. UserChatRoom hasOne ChatRoom, ChatRoom belongsTo UserChatRoom. Also, your relationships should be placed in each model, not in your index.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType){
    var ChatRoom = sequelize.define("ChatRoom",{
        idChatUser: {
            type: DataType.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        //etc

    }, {
      classMethods: {
        //models/index.js calls this function
        associate: function(models) {
          ChatRoom.belongsTo(UserCharRoom, {foreignKey: 'something'});
        }
      }
    })

    return ChatRoom;

}
```